# QGIS Plugin, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm writing a plugin for qgis. In this plugin I need to query a db and I tried to use pymysql. When I try to install the plugin in Qgis the message error is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'`. Pymsql is correctly installed and it usually works, and i'm sure that in the code I imported the module. This is the code part where I use the db connection. Is there a problem with my code or is it impossible to use pymysql in a Qgis plugin?

```
    retrive = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM `beni` Join relazioni ON beni.ID = relazioni.IDR WHERE relazioni.data="+dataInizio

    #database connection
    connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",database="mydb",port=3308 )
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    if connection.open:
      #execute query
      cursor.execute(retrive)
      rows = cursor.fetchall()

      if not rows:
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
        'Success', "rows is empty", level=Qgis.Success)
      else:
        #create Qgis Expression
        seperator = ', '
        rowsString=seperator.join(rows)
        expr = QgsExpression( "id in ("+rowsString+")")
        cLayer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
        it = cLayer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
        ids = [i.id() for i in it]

        #select by ids and load style
        cLayer.selectByIds(ids)
        cLayer.loadNamedStyle(selectedStyle)
        cLayer.triggerRepaint()

    connection.close()
```